# How can i delete the contents of the spool\PRINTERS directory remotely via powershell without WinRM

Tags: powershell

I need to be able to pass credentials through, which i have local administrator credential for the remote machine.

I only need to target one machine at a time, which will be manually specified in a function and the IP will be assigned as a $Global:var

I can use WMI-GetObject and stop/start the printer spool service, but cannot figure out a way to delete the remote files while passing credentials without using invoke, which doesnt work as WinRM is not enabled (and cannot be by policy)

Thank you for any help you can offer.

I have a test setup i can test as much as needed

also let me know if this would suit SuperUser more than StackOverflow

Comment: How about setting up a scheduled task on the target system that deletes the files, then triggering it remotely with [schtasks.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/schtasks) when required?  I assume this works via the Task Scheduler service independent of WMI or PowerShell, but I don't know what ports/rights you might need for the connection.

Answer (score 0):

In the end i could not find a solution in powershell itself, so i defaulted to a co-located Batch file to handle the windows file operations and called the batch file from powershell with

```
start-process -Wait "cmd.exe" "/c c:\powershell\clearspool.bat"
```

batch file is below

```
@ECHO off
rem Set up the remote server ip
set User=administrator
set /p Server=Enter Server IP: 
set /p Password=Enter Admin Password: 

rem Mount the remote path
net use \\%Server%\c$\Windows\System32\spool %Password% /USER:%User%

rem Delete a file
del /S /F \\%Server%\c$\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS 

rem Unmount the remote path
net use \\%Server%\c$\Windows\System32\spool /delete
```